# how to store javascript variable in php

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
    var x = document.getElementById("billing:postcode").value;
    <?php
 $pincode =  "<script>document.writeln(x);</script>";
$collection = Mage::getModel('cod/cod')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('pincode', $pincode)->addFieldToFilter('status',1);
 ?>
alert(<?php echo count($collection) ?>);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Please follow this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662927/how-can-i-store-javascript-variable-output-into-a-php-variable

Comment: it's not working i already tried this. can you please help me to solve in my above code

Comment: This can not work as basic rules of web application development!
Javascript executes at client side (browser) and PHP at server.
If you are setting var x in Javascript then you can never get it in PHP .

Comment: how can i solve this in javascript